# google map using sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, sencha-touch-2

I am absolutely new with sencha touch 2.

I want to make a simple google map application.

Please tell how to develop it step by step, and give me map applications if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please tell us what you have tried so far, especially any code you have tried.

Comment: Also, read the fine manual: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Map

Comment: i want to show google map in tabpanel, i don't know how to use the example menoted in sencha docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/oreilly/ which also comes as example bundled with sencha touch sdk. This one has map in tabbed panel and you can look at code also.